# Data aggregation by sliding time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, datediff, sliding-window

*[Query and question edited and fixed thanks to comments from @Gordon Linoff and @shawnt00]*

I recently inherited a SQL query that calculates the number of some events in time windows of 30 days from a log database. It uses a CTE (Common Table Expression) to generate the 30 days ranges since '2019-01-01' to now. And then it counts the cases in those 30/60/90 days intervals.  I am not sure this is the best method. All I know is that it takes a long time to run and I do not understand 100% how exactly it works.  So I am trying to rebuild it in an efficient way (maybe as it is now is the most efficient way, I do not know).

I have several questions:

1. One of the things I notice is that instead of using DATEDIFF the query simply substracts a number of days from the date.Is that a good practice at all?
2. Is there a better way of doing the time comparisons?
3. Is there a better way to do the whole thing? The bottom line is: I need to aggregate data by number of occurrences in time periods of 30, 60 and 90 days.

Note: LogDate original format is like *2019-04-01 18:30:12.000*.

```
DECLARE @dt1 Datetime='2019-01-01'
DECLARE @dt2 Datetime=getDate();

WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [Dates]=@dt1 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [dates] + 30 
         FROM   ctedaterange 
         WHERE  [dates] + 30<= @dt2) 

SELECT 
[dates], 
lt.Activity, COUNT(*) as Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lt.LogDate <= dates and lt.LogDate > dates - 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Activity90days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lt.LogDate <= dates and lt.LogDate > dates - 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Activity60days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN lt.LogDate <= dates and lt.LogDate > dates - 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Activity30days
FROM   ctedaterange AS cte
JOIN (SELECT Activity, CONVERT(DATE, LogDate) as LogDate FROM LogTable) AS lt
ON cte.[dates] = lt.LogDate
group by [dates], lt.Activity
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Sample dataset (LogTable):

```
LogDate, Activity
2020-02-25 01:10:10.000, Activity01
2020-04-14 01:12:10.000, Activity02
2020-08-18 02:03:53.000, Activity02
2019-10-29 12:25:55.000, Activity01
2019-12-24 18:11:11.000, Activity03
2019-04-02 03:33:09.000, Activity01
```

Expected Output  (the output does not reflect the data shown above for I would need too many lines in the sample set to be shown in this post)

As I said above, the bottom line is: I need to aggregate data by number of occurrences in time periods of 30, 60 and 90 days.

```
Activity, Activity90days, Activity60days, Activity30days
Activity01, 3, 0, 1
Activity02, 1, 10, 2
Activity03, 5, 1, 3
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Your question talks about one timeframe, but the question contains other timeframes.

Comment: This is creating a list of all dates and then counting the number of log events on each date. It handles those dates where no events were recorded. There's apparently a join missing between the two tables though which probably explains why it's slow (and I doubt the numbers are correct either.)

Comment: Also, you're grouping by `lt.Activity` yet return `lt.Event` unaggregated. This should cause an error.

Comment: Sorry Gordon and Shawnt, I pasted from different queries. I fixed the timeframes.   I will add some sample data.

Comment: Hi @shawnt00, what would be the missing join?

Comment: Are these supposed to be rolling windows relative to each date? Or is it just intended to look back from current date?

Comment: Hi @shawnt00. They are supposed to be rolling windows relative to each date.  I added the JOIN as I believe it has to go. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to cast `LogDate` to type `date` in order for the join to work. Since you know each date is present for each row-activity combo just use `sum(count(LogDate)) over (partition by Activity order by [dates] with rows between 89 preceding and current row)` Repeat for the other two windows.

Comment: Thank you @shawnt00.  I need some time to wrap my head around it but I understand the general idea.  I will try it and will post the results.  Thank you!

Comment: @shawnt00, if you want you can add your comment an an answer so I can mark it as correct, that really helped me. Now my query is way faster.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't yet have the option to range over *values* of the window frame of an analytic function. Since you've generated all possible dates though and you've already got the counts by date, it's very easy to look back a specific number of (aggregated) rows to get the right totals. Here is my suggested expression for 90 days:

```
sum(count(LogDate)) over (
    partition by Activity order by [dates]
    with rows between 89 preceding and current row
)
```